# Best way to perform Update call when input field value is changed in Meteor JS?

Tags: meteor

Hypothetical example - you have an "Items" collection, where each item has a quantity and price that's stored in the db.

That quantity is an input field.

We want the database to be updated when the quantity is changed - with no "submit" button. There are multiple ways of going about this. Two examples:

1. Update db on "changed":

   ```
   'change input.qty': function (evt) {
       var qty = $(evt.target).val();
       if (qty==null){
           qty=0;
       };
       Items.update(this._id,{$set:{quantity: Number(qty)}});
   },
   ```
2. Update db on "keyup":

   ```
   'keyup input.qty': function (evt) {
       var qty = $(evt.target).val();
       if (qty==null){
           qty=0;
       };
       Items.update(this._id,{$set:{quantity: Number(qty)}});
   },
   ```

1 is more efficient - it only performs the update call once, after the user has clicked outside of the input box. However, it's a worse user experience, because the updates are not reflected on the page as they're typing. (For example, say the "price" field is calculated reactively based on your input quantity)

2 is a better user experience but can be extremely inefficient(ie typing in 103.58 makes FIVE database calls)

Are there better alternatives or a good middle ground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I usually attack this problem:

```
var handle = null;
------------------------
'input input.qty': function (evt) {
    var self = this;
    if (handle)
        clearTimeout(handle);
    handle = setTimeout(function () {
        var qty = $(evt.target).val();
        if (qty==null){
            qty=0;
        };
        Items.update(self._id,{$set:{quantity: Number(qty)}});
    }, 500);
},
```

You can play with the number 500 a bit to get it to your liking. With this solution you'll only get a database call when the user has stopped typing for 500 milliseconds.

I'd switch to the [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) as well, it takes care of cut, paste, and key entries.

Answer (score 5):

That's the exact situation for which [`_.throttle`](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) method was created.

```
'keyup input.qty': _.throttle(function (evt) {
  ...
}, 350),
```

When you wrap your handler with `_.throttle` that way, it will be called only once per the given number of milliseconds, even if the input keep changing more frequently.

`350` is a good value in most cases, though the exact optimum value may depend on the interface you're designing.

Comment: Cool, but I'd mention passing it { leading: false }. The docs say by default it'll run the first time then start to throttle, which unnecessarily doubles the number of calls to the server. Also keyup won't catch paste events

Answer (score 3):

Plagiarising @Hubert OG's answer, except to recommend the "debounce" function instead, and the "input" & "change" events. (`_.debounce` works the same as the accepted solution from @Dave without the boilerplate.)

That's the exact situation for which [`_.debounce`](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) method was created.

```
'input input.qty, change input.qty': _.debounce(function (evt) {
  ...
}, 350),
```

When you wrap your handler with `_.debounce` that way, it will be called only once  after all input has stopped (for at least a given number of msec)

Comment: Note that this solution will behave weirdly if that template is rendered in multiple places. If the user types into one of the template instances, then quickly (within 350ms) switches to the other and types into that, the changes on the first one will be lost. To prevent this, call `_.debounce` in `Template.whatever.created` and store the debounced function on the template instance, then in the event handler, call the debounced version which you stored. That way, there's a unique debounced function for each template instance.

Answer (score 0):

Both seem like good solutions. The first is better in my opinion - keyup also registers things like pressing enter or other keys. Since I have multiple items with multiple quantity fields, here's what I ended up going with:

```
var handle = [];

'input input.qty': function (evt) {
    var id = this._id;
    if (handle[id]){
      clearTimeout(handle[id]);
    }
    handle[id] = setTimeout(function () {
      var qty = $(evt.target).val();
      Items.update(id,{$set:{quantity: Number(qty)}});
    }, 750);
}
```

Comment: One added benefit of this approach is you can still do other things every time the event fires, and just throttle the save to the server which can sometimes be useful.